# Projectile is not ignoring files

Tags: projectile

I followed the [docs here](https://docs.projectile.mx/projectile/projects.html#ignoring-files) and added lines to `.projectile` like

```
-/build
-/Docs/doxy
```

I did that because I want typical [projectile](https://projectile.mx) commands to ignore those sub-directories in my project directory.

My "project" is pretty typical. It is a hierarchy of directories with source code files, `CMakeLists.txt`, and other things. I put this  `.projectile` file in the root folder to mark it as a project for projectile. That part seems to work, because the various projectile commands seem to be using that folder as a project root now.

However, when I run `projectile-find-file`, and then type part of a filename in the minibuffer, it doesn't just match against source code, it matches object files in the `build` directory, and `.html` files generated by doxygen in the `Docs/doxy` directory. I usually don't want to open these things in emacs, and I'd like it to ignore these files.

Shouldn't it be ignoring them, because I added those lines in the `.projectile` file?

Maybe I should also mention I enabled IDO with `(ido-mode t)` so when I'm typing in the minibuffer to find the file it's matching any file in the tree, going into subdirectories. Eg, I type "View.cc", and the displayed list of potential matches looks like:

```
MyApp/BrowserView.cc     (good)
MyApp/PracticeView.cc
MyLib/UILib/View.cc
build/CMakeFiles/.../BrowserView.cc.o    (bad)
... many more ...
```

Comment: Please summarize what actions you took - a recipe, instead of just providing a link.

Comment: I've updated the question to try to explain a bit more.

Comment: Thx............

Comment: Just a wild guess, it may or may not work ... Projectile has a cache.  May be it hasn't refreshed the cache after you have update `.projectile.   Try creating the project refresh, or re-create the project cache using one of the projectile's cache commands.

Comment: I tried `projectile-invalidate-cache`, and restarting emacs. No luck.